# angular style.background-image binding

Tags: angular, ngx-admin

in ngx-admin, there is

```
style.background-image
```

attribute,

which library parses this style.background-image ?

```
  <div class="cover" style.background-image="url('{{track.cover}}')"></div>
```

https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/blob/5e44070239e3b133aeb97b57bd59d04867ee1eb3/src/app/pages/dashboard/rooms/player/player.component.html#L6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method of applying style is know as applying the style using [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding) and Angular itself parses this. In Angular we normally bind the component properties in our template, but we can bind attributes too in our template.

Here `background-image` is an attribute of style which is getting bound to cover property of the track object.

Comment: interestingly it is still valid without the square bracket?